# Installing CUDA 7.5 on Debian with packaged bumblebee

Tags: debian, nvidia, optimus, bumblebee, cuda

My laptop, which runs Debian Jessie, has switchable graphics cards (Intel + NVIDIA GT 520M), and for this I have installed Bumblebee & Primus, which depends on the NVIDIA driver in the package manager. Now I need to install CUDA 7.5, and therefore need a more recent driver (even the backports one is too old). However, to install the one bundled with CUDA, I need to remove the one from the package manager, which is not allowed due to the dependency.

How can I make the packaged bumblebee work while using a non packaged driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve it, so eventually I resorted to switching to Ubuntu (Linux Mint), and then install the official DEB-package from Nvidia. Now it all works great, although I'm using Nvidia Prime instead of Bumblebee.

Comment: Switching distributions is not really solving the problem, it's more like avoiding it.